# Sort a python dictionary based on input value?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary with four keys `a`,`b`,`c`,`d` with values `100`,`200`,`300`,`400`

```
list1 = {'a':'100','b':'200','c':'300','d':'400'}
```

And a variable `inputs`.

```
inputs = 'c'
```

If inputs is `c`. The `list1` dictionary has to be sorted based on it.

```
inputs = 'c'
list1 = {'c':'300','a':'100','b':'200','d':'400'}

inputs = 'b'
list1 = {'b':'200','a':'100','c':'300','d':'400'}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Python3.7+ dict keys are stored in the insertion order

```
k ='c'
d={k:list1[k]}
for key in list1:
    if key!=k:
        d[key]=list1[key]
```

Output

```
{'c': '300', 'a': '100', 'b': '200', 'd': '400'}
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you just want to rearrange your dict to have the chosen value at the front, then the remaining keys afterwards:

```
dict1 = {'a':'100','b':'200','c':'300','d':'400'}

key = 'c'

result = {key: dict1[key], **{k: v for k, v in dict1.items() if k != key}}

print(result)
# {'c': '300', 'a': '100', 'b': '200', 'd': '400'}
```

The `**` simply merges the leftover filtered keys with `key: dict1[key]`.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to change the position to the first one a given value if it exists, it could be done in the following way:

```
list1 = {'a':'100','b':'200','c':'300','d':'400'}

inputs = 'c'

output = {}

if inputs in list1.keys():
    output[inputs] = list1.get(inputs)

for i in list1.keys():
    output[i] = list1[i]
```

Output;

```
{'c': '300', 'a': '100', 'b': '200', 'd': '400'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one-liner:

```
d = {'a':'100','b':'200','c':'300','d':'400'}
i = input()

d = {i:d[i],**{k:d[k] for k in d if k!=i}}

print(list1)
```

Input:

```
c
```

Output:

```
{'a': '100', 'b': '200', 'd': '400', 'c': '300'}
```